# How to prevent a make recipe from running before the same previous make command has finished

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I'm building a hugo site via a make command, typically triggered by a git hook after pushing some files.

It's working well, but I'm paranoid that at some point the build will happen concurrently and this will cause conflicts or corruption somehow.

Is there a way to tell a make recipe not to execute if a previous invocation of the recipe has not finished yet?

A test for this could be something like:

```bash
test:
        printf "Start run of make recipe at $$(date)\n" &> demo.txt && sleep 30s && printf "Finish run of make recipe at $$(date)" &>> demo.txt &
```

If you run `make test`, then again run `make test` within the 30s sleep window, the demo.txt file is immediately overwritten with the output of the second iteration.

I have not been able to use job management or `wait` to prevent the overwrite.

Comment: Does Hugo not follow the regular best practice and update files atomically? (Doing so involves writing to a temporary file on the same filesystem, flushing it to disk, and renaming it over the original only after that flush is complete; it's safe to have multiple processes doing that concurrently).

Comment: Anyhow, the easy answer is whichever of `flock` or `lockfile` your operating system provides, but if you need them, Hugo should do better.

Comment: There is no facility in `make` to prevent two instances of make from being invoked at the same time.  So if you want such a facility you'll have to do it on your own, outside of `make` (that is, before you invoke `make`).  There are many ways to do it, as Charles alludes to.

Comment: Thanks both. I imagine the atomic updating described by Charles is why I haven't seen any issues with this so far, but I didn't know it existed. So, I will probably just let these concurrent processes happen and not worry about them until something blows up.